# How to make a textbox invisible when radio button checked

Tags: c#, radio-button

I am working on C# application. I have 10 radio buttons in a group panel, so now if I only checked the radioButton10 then textBox1 will be visible, if I checked someone of the other radio Buttons (radioButton1 .... radioButton9) then textBox1 should be invisible.
I wrote the following code but the textBox1 is still visible. If the code is right where can I wrote it(form load, some function ... etc) if it's NOT, then Please Help.

```
    public TeamInfoForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showTeam();
        if (radioButton10 .Checked)
            textBox1 .Visible = true;
        else
            textBox1 .Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: If you set a break point does it ever reach that if statement?

Comment: Please post more code? Where do you have the code above? In which method?

Comment: yes, it has been reached, but the problem is, the textBox1 take only the first operation checked or not, if change the checked to un checked nothing will happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to implement the event that occur when you check or uncheck the radiobutton. Try to imlpement "OnCheckChanged" event for the radiobutton and you have to set autopostback to true if you want that the event occurs, otherwise the event won't work.

Comment: BIG YES. I did it with CheckedChange event. YAHOOOOOOOO Thanks dude.

Comment: _"have to set autopostback to true"_ winforms hence unnecessary

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab: he's probably using winforms(group panel --> `GroupBox`). There's no `AutoPostBack` in winforms since there's no postback.

Comment: @Tim: I didn't know that he was using winform for that. That's true that autopostback is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Initially you have to set the Visible property of textBox1 to false in Forms Designer. Otherwise you can set it in FormInitialize() method. Next you have write code like below

```
    public void ToggleTextBox()
    {
        textBox1.Visible = radioButton3.Checked;
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleTextBox();
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleTextBox();
    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleTextBox();
    }
```

Comment: This worked great for me, perfect solution to my needs.